# Image of subgroup under group automorphism lies in itself

Tags: group-theory

Let $ G $ be a group, $ H \leq G $ a subgroup and $ \sigma \in \text{Aut}(G) $ an automorphism of $ G $. I want to prove that if $ \sigma(H) \subseteq H $ that $ \sigma(H) = H $ is true. If $ H $ is finite, this is obvious.

I don't know how to show it in the general case. Or if there is even a counterexample.

Comment: Note that it becomes true if you assume it holds for all automorphisms, rather than just for a specified one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take $G$ to be the rationals under addition, let $\sigma(x)=2x$ be the automorphism of the group. Let $H=\mathbb{Z}$ be your subgroup, then clearly $\sigma(H)=2\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}=H$, but it is clear that $\sigma(H)\ne H$.

Comment: Thank you so much! This almost has driven me mad. I also thought of $ \mathbb{Z} $ and $ 2\mathbb{Z} $, but not as subgroups of $ \mathbb{Q} $.